# Change hover color on nav-tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to change text color of hover nav-tabs, so I named : nav nav-tabs custom, so code in my view looks like this:

```
      <li class="active"><%= link_to "Overview", '#'  %>           
      </li>
      <li><%= link_to "About",    '#' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "What we do", '#' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Partners", '#' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", '#' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Support", '#' %></li>
    </ul>
```

and code in my custom.css.scss

```
.custom a:hover {color: black;}
```

and it doesn't work. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to make your selector a little bit more specific to properly target your tabs. Try this:

```
.custom > li > a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

By the way, this only changes the color of the text, if you want to change the background color of the tabs upon hover switch that `color` property to `background-color`.

Comment: What you will say, if I tell you, that your code don't change colors in my application ? Where is the issue ?

Comment: @DenysMedynskyi Are you placing the `.custom` class on the nav-tabs container? Here is a simple demo i put up showing how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ayuRm/

Comment: I had code like yours, but it doesn't work. I even insert your code instead of mine. I just can't get why ?

Comment: @DenysMedynskyi Where are you writing the css? on your own stylesheet or the bootstrap stylesheet and in what order are they being placed in the header of your page?

Comment: I'm writing css in my custom.css.scss file.
I'm creating header using [link](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#top) Listing 5.10.

Comment: @DenysMedynskyi would have to take a look at your page to diagnose the issue, the method i posted above works just fine with the default bootstrap installation so it must be something local to your setup. Can you post a link?

Answer (score 3):

Andres is right about the specificity. The style you want to override is set with:

```
.nav-bar > li > a:hover
```

If you're using LESS with Twitter Bootstrap there are variables already made for this:

```
@navbarLinkColor
@navbarLinkColorHover
@navbarLinkColorActive
```

See the [Navbar](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html) section of the docs.

Comment: Thanks for help, but the previous post doesn't help me. Can you tell why ? 
And one more question. I wrote in my scss file



      @navbarLinkColorHover: @grayDarker;



this line, and error says 

Invalid CSS after "...LinkColorHover:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " @grayDarker;"

Where is my error?

Comment: Change .nav-bar to .nav-tabs for your example and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me without much "specificity" other than the default Bootstrap...

```css
ul.nav > li > a:hover {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 border-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set @navbarLinkBackgroundHover